# How can i add trigger event in mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have trigger statement but its not working

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table3_insert BEFORE INSERT ON rd_stonepanel_pricing
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table3_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.option_id = CONCAT('R', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
```

> But it shows an error like   You have an error in your SQL syntax: 
>   `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '' at line 3`

Comment: You have multiple statement in the trigger so you need to wrap them in a begin..end and set delimiters,https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to update a sequence when an insert is done. See this(http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/custom-auto-increment-values/).

The below code snippet may work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table3_insert BEFORE INSERT ON rd_stonepanel_pricing
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table3_seq SET option_id = CONCAT('R', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0');
  END;
```

Remove the semicolon at line 3 if it is a single statement and add end. Also, the above code will only work if the table "table3_seq" has one column.